# Retain single row from a group in SQL?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table, sample as below and I would like to obtain a single row for unique values of col1:

```
col1 col2 col3
1     a    b
1     c    d
1     e    f
2     g    h
2     i    j
3     k    l
```

I would like to obtain a table, sample1 as below:

```
col1 col2 col3
1     a    b
2     g    h
3     k    l
```

How to achieve it using SQL?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the GROUP BY clause. 
You can read the documentation for more information: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php

Example:

```
SELECT fields FROM table GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: I can't help you if you just reply with "This doesn't work". Show your query or at least some data for me to look into.

Comment: I got the correct answer. As mentioned in the link by HRgiger.